# Does parallel processing help to execute async-await code more faster in c#?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, async-await

I have multi-core laptop and I wanna make my application more faster on that machine, I think async-await and parallel programming help to achieve that feat.

Comment: You can trigger multiple async operations in parallel, and then await their completion afterwards, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: You can have a million cores, if it isn't doing the work, then it won't be faster.

Comment: Without knowing what your are doing there is no way to provide *concrete* answer to this questions. I.e. trying to run true sequential code with async/await or multithreading or any other form that allows parallelization of execution will only slow code down as parallelization is not free...

Answer (score 1):

Typically, Async and await is more about not blocking the current thread during a long-running operation.

Typically, parallel processing is used when the goal is to achieve an increase in performance.

That said, I think it's not uncommon to see both used together--you might have a desktop app that you want to ensure the UI thread is not blocked while you perform a long-running operation

- so you could use Async and await to start the long-running operation on a non-UI thread (this way, your desktop app's GUI can still be responsive while the long-running operation is running on another thread
- and you might also decide to introduce parallelism in the implementation of that long-running operation to have it complete faster